# Angular initial data load, defer directives until after initialise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to load some data into my angular app the first time it is loaded. The data needs to come from the server.

My app currently consists of a number of directives on a single view in an accordion. The directives are forms whose criteria needs to be met before the user can progress to the next accordion group. The first accordion group needs to use the data from the server to display to the user, there is a dependency on the data for the view.

What is the best way to inject this data in the first instance?

I could move the initial data call into the first directive but it doesn't really feel like it is 'its' job. I could create another directive to handle this load but then I would need manage the load order of the directives. I have had a look at ng-init which works well until the server call is made, during this call the directives run before it completes.

Any of the above would work for me in theory but i'm not sure that they are the best approach. What would you suggest is the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: are you using any router in your app? Which?

Comment: what scope are you using in your directives?

Comment: @hitmands $routeProvider -ngRoute for routing

Comment: @TarunDugar Isolated Scope for directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a resolve in your state, so, both views and controllers are called when the resolution is done.

have a look at this link: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate your directives with ng-if attribute and, as value, pass a scope property that will indicate data load ex.